# Dynamic React form with multiple values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a dynamic React form where users can select multiple values from a dropdown menu which then gets saved. I managed to find this example however implementing  and adding the attribute multiple doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Expected result: The user should be able to select multiple values such as Item A and Item B. They can then add another select option but this time choose Item B for example, preserving the last values set.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { values: [] };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  createUI() {
    return this.state.values.map((el, i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <select
          multiple={true}
          value={el || ""}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)}
        >
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="10">Item A</option>
          <option value="20">Item B</option>
        </select>{" "}
        <input
          type="button"
          value="remove"
          onClick={this.removeClick.bind(this, i)}
        />
      </div>
    ));
  }

  handleChange(i, event) {
    let values = [...this.state.values];
    values[i] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ values });
  }

  addClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ values: [...prevState.values, ""] }));
  }

  removeClick(i) {
    let values = [...this.state.values];
    values.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({ values });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert("A name was submitted: " + this.state.values.join(", "));
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        {this.createUI()}
        <input
          type="button"
          value="add more"
          onClick={this.addClick.bind(this)}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want make each selections independent for each select box and should be able to submit as whole.

you can update the handleChange method with array of selected value.

```
  handleChange(i, event) {
    let values = [...this.state.values];

    // change
    values[i] = Array.from(
      event.target.selectedOptions,
      (option) => option.value
    );

    this.setState({ values });
  }
```

you can following this code link [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-frost-p7diz)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the selections of `Select` and in the `value` attribute you need to pass the selected value options.

Working Example - [CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multiple-select-stackoverflow-64918838-dhql6)

**Code -**

```
handleChange(i, e) {
    let target = e.target;
    let name = target.name;
    let value = Array.from(target.selectedOptions, (option) => option.value);
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  createUI() {
    return this.state.values.map((el, i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <select
          name="selectOptions"
          multiple={true}
          value={this.state.selectOptions}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)}
        >
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="10">Item A</option>
          <option value="20">Item B</option>
        </select>{" "}
        <input
          type="button"
          value="remove"
          onClick={this.removeClick.bind(this, i)}
        />
      </div>
    ));
  }
```

Comment: This changes the values for each option. I'm trying to get it so that if you select Item A and B in the first option, and then select Item B in the second option, then both values are stored. This seems to change the values for all options. Thanks

Comment: @user14649590 : You need to modify the array of values for this, my example is for individual multiple selection, with this u can expand it further.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem that I see is the `multiple` value you set to `select`. You only need set it `true` when you're passing array as `value` property. But you're not doing it. So remove the `multiple={true}` and you're good to go.

Your approach seems to be fine. At the end, when for example the user selects *A*, *select*, *B*, the `this.state.values` would log `["10", "", "20"]`.

P.S: If you're a new React developer and the project is new I highly recommend you using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and get rid of all `this`, `bind` and class components.